# “Paragraph ended before \verbatim@ was complete.” when trying to use verbatim in tabular

Tags: tables, verbatim

I have the following code in my Beamer slide code:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{selections}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
sample 1 &
\begin{minipage}{3in}
\begin{verbatim}
sample 2
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
```

When I try to compile, it breaks with the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
sample 2 \end {verbatim} \end {minipage}\\ \end {tabular} 
! Paragraph ended before \verbatim@ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.965 \end{frame}

?
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. Could anyone offer me guidance?

Comment: Try `\begin{frame}[fragile]` (untested as you didn't provide a complete example).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to provide an answer?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `\begin{frame}[fragile]`. This option is needed when the content contains verbatim.

Comment: Hi @Ulrike Fischer. Thank you very much for your solution. If you don't mind my asking, how did you know this to be the solution? How would one interpret the error message as being that the standard frame cannot really contain the verbatim environment? Is there documentation that details this?

Comment: The documentation of beamer describes this problem in various places. And you really not the first getting errors due to verbatim content. When I see the trigger words "beamer + verbatim + error" the first guess is "missing fragile option".

Comment: Thank you so much for this - because it also holds when an environment is implicitly verbatim, which may not be immediately evident.  (Such as in SageTeX.)

Comment: I am having this same error, but I am not using "frame" at all.  I am using "texttt" and the text within that seems perfectly normal.  Any idea at all what I should look for.  Would really like to know WHY "fragile" help and how that understanding might help with my problem.

Comment: @AgilePro ask a new question with a minimal example.